# Get Average Values within Array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

Hi I have an array which looks like the following:

```
[
  {
    group: "23",
    delays: [
      { Station: "a", Arrival: "3", Departure: 0 },
      { Station: "b", Arrival: -179, Departure: 0 },
      { Station: "c", Arrival: -156, Departure: 0 },
    ],
  },
  {
    group: "23",
    delays: [
      { Station: "a", Arrival: "5", Departure: 79 },
      { Station: "b", Arrival: 0, Departure: 0 },
      { Station: "c", Arrival: 68, Departure: 68 },
    ],
  },
];
```

Uptil now I have been able to eliminate duplicates and add up the variables... however I wish to get the average of these values instead of summing them up.
This is the code for summing them up, what would be the best way to incorporate a "calculate average" function? Say Station b appears twice, then I would divide sum of Station b by two.

```
var dataPoints = [];
var xs = [];
var n = [];

function addData(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < data[i].delays.length; j++) {
            dataPoints.push({
                x: data[i].delays[j].Station,
                y: data[i].delays[j].Arrival
            });
        }
    }
    
    values = ["no information"]
    dataPoints = dataPoints.filter(item => !values.includes(item.y));
    
    dataPoints.forEach((e) => {
        if (!xs.includes(e.x)) { n.push(e); xs.push(e.x) }
        else { n.forEach(f => f.y += f.x == e.x ? e.y : 0) }
        // make a change here to get average of duplicate stations  
        // Say Station b appears twice, then I would divide sum of 
        // Station b by two.
    })

    console.log(n)
```

Comment: what is the desired result?

Comment: instead of summing up the y values from the array, i wish to get the average

Comment: ez answer: `You calculate an average by adding all the elements and then dividing by the number of elements.`

Comment: @luthienaerendell add expected code in the question itself

Comment: @johnSmith so i have to add a counter variable yes? or do i divide by array.length i'm sorry i am quite new to javascript

Comment: @luthienaerendell you could, but easier would be this pseudo-code. `avg = summed_up / items.length`

Comment: @johnSmith but that would be the average of all elements... i would like to divide by the amount of duplicates? say is station b appears twice, then i would divide the sum by 2. 
i have changed the line to the following f.y += f.x / f.length
is this correct?

Comment: @luthienaerendell That's why I asked you to put the desired result in the question itself, because it si not clear whose average do you want...

Comment: @decpk sorry currrently i am unable to edit it for some reason... could you read my comment above and confirm if the change i made is correct?

Comment: still no luck @luthienaerendell

Comment: @decpk how about now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code after you get `dataPoints`

```
const map = new Map();
  dataPoints.forEach(({ x, y }) => {
    const [total, count] = map.get(x) ?? [null, 0];
    map.set(x, [(total ?? 0) + parseInt(y), count + 1]);
  });

  n = [...map].map(([k, v]) => ({ x: k, y: v[0] / v[1] }));
```

I've duplicated the station `c` in first object.

I've used [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) here to store the `total` and `count` in an array.

```js
const data = [
  {
    group: "23",
    delays: [
      { Station: "a", Arrival: "3", Departure: 0 },
      { Station: "b", Arrival: -179, Departure: 0 },
      { Station: "c", Arrival: -156, Departure: 0 },
      { Station: "c", Arrival: 157, Departure: 0 },
    ],
  },
  {
    group: "23",
    delays: [
      { Station: "d", Arrival: "5", Departure: 79 },
      { Station: "f", Arrival: 0, Departure: 0 },
      { Station: "g", Arrival: 68, Departure: 68 },
    ],
  },
];

var dataPoints = [];
var xs = [];
var n = [];

function addData(data) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < data[i].delays.length; j++) {
      dataPoints.push({
        x: data[i].delays[j].Station,
        y: data[i].delays[j].Arrival,
      });
    }
  }

  values = ["no information"];
  dataPoints = dataPoints.filter((item) => !values.includes(item.y));

  const map = new Map();
  dataPoints.forEach(({ x, y }) => {
    const [total, count] = map.get(x) ?? [null, 0];
    map.set(x, [(total ?? 0) + parseInt(y), count + 1]);
  });

  n = [...map].map(([k, v]) => ({ x: k, y: v[0] / v[1] }));
  console.log(n);
}

addData(data);
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output fill height. So IGNORE IT */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I've just started code after OP gets `dataPoints`

Comment: @RoboRobok OP mentioned in the question *make a change here to get average of duplicate stations*

Comment: Would be easier if you just posted the change.

Comment: thanks so much! this really helped as i was not sure how to get the total amount of duplicates stored